# Pandas Compare Value to Mean of previous rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given the following data,

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['AAA','2019-01-01', 10], ['AAA','2019-01-02', 21],
        ['AAA','2019-02-01', 30], ['AAA','2019-02-02', 45],
        ['BBB','2019-01-01', 50], ['BBB','2019-01-02', 60],
        ['BBB','2019-02-01', 70],['BBB','2019-02-02', 59]]

dfx = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['NAME', 'TIMESTAMP','VALUE'])

  NAME   TIMESTAMP  VALUE
0  AAA  2019-01-01     10
1  AAA  2019-01-02     21
2  AAA  2019-02-01     30
3  AAA  2019-02-02     45
4  BBB  2019-01-01     50
5  BBB  2019-01-02     60
6  BBB  2019-02-01     70
7  BBB  2019-02-02     59
```

Is it possible to compare the last value of each group ('NAME') to the mean of the previous 3 rows, so the expected output would be somewhat like the following,

```
  NAME   TIMESTAMP  VALUE  RESULT
0  AAA  2019-01-01     10  
1  AAA  2019-01-02     21  
2  AAA  2019-02-01     30   
3  AAA  2019-02-02     45  False
4  BBB  2019-01-01     50
5  BBB  2019-01-02     60  
6  BBB  2019-02-01     70  
7  BBB  2019-02-02     59  True
```

So the Result is False for Group 'AAA' because the value 45 is 'Greater Than' the mean of the previous 3 values (10+21+30), while the Result is True for Group 'BBB' because the value 59 is 'Lesser Than' the mean of the previous 3 values (50+60+70).

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
def compare(a, b):
    if a > b:
        return False
    elif a < b: 
        return True 

dfx['rolling_mean'] = dfx.VALUE.rolling(3, 3).mean()
s = dfx.duplicated('NAME', keep = 'last')
dfx['RESULT'] = dfx[~s].apply(lambda x: compare(x.VALUE, x.rolling_mean), axis = 1)
```

Comment: Nice one, this should generlize more easily to compare rows in the middle of the datafarme.

Comment: Thanks DarkDrassher34 this works, but as with the solution from @WeNYoBen this too works only for the last row, I guess I screwed up when I asked my question, but each value should be compared not just the last row.

Comment: Originally, I had it for all the rows, but then changed it when I saw @WeNYoBen's answer. Your expected output says otherwise. If you could provide more data with a clearer expected output, I can generalize the code for your use-case.

Comment: If you want for all rows, then remove the line where `s` is defined and replace `dfx[~s]` with `dfx` in the last line of code.

Comment: Thanks @DarkDrassher34, I guess, the only part missing was the group by but I managed to fix that. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: No problem :) Let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 1):

Use `duplicated`

```
s=dfx.duplicated('NAME',keep='last')
dfx['RESULT']=dfx[~s].VALUE.le(dfx[s].groupby('NAME')['VALUE'].mean().values)
dfx
  NAME   TIMESTAMP  VALUE RESULT
0  AAA  2019-01-01     10    NaN
1  AAA  2019-01-02     21    NaN
2  AAA  2019-02-01     30    NaN
3  AAA  2019-02-02     45  False
4  BBB  2019-01-01     50    NaN
5  BBB  2019-01-02     60    NaN
6  BBB  2019-02-01     70    NaN
7  BBB  2019-02-02     59   True
```